# Как преобразовать массив с объектами в просто объекты?

Tags: php, json

Есть массив объектов

```
[{"phone":"+79111111111"},{"name":"test"},{"id":53}]
```

нужно преобразовать в

```
{"phone":"+79111111111","name":"test","id":53}
```

Подскажите.

Comment: что у вас не получилось? работа с json? цикл?

Comment: у меня просто все данных приходят в формате, который нужен мне, а вот второй приходит, как показано выше. Вот что-то никак не могу вразумить как мне написать так, чтобы данные сначала подготовить, а потом записать, чтобы не переписывать уйму кода.

Comment: чего уйма - один цикл по сбору ключ-значение из массива массивов? Ваша репутация не позволяет думать, что вы не умеете писать циклы

Comment: @splash58 давно не работал с данными, забыл совсем как делать... Я знаю, что одним циклом это делает, то вот что-то я не могу его никак составить (позорище знаю). (Рука лицо)

Comment: `foreach($outer as $inner) foreach($inner as $k=>$v) $result[$k] => $v;`

Comment: @splash58 точно, двумя циклами, а я что-то одним кручу верчу. Спасибо. Год ничего не писал.